# Save multiple models at a time in Yii2

Tags: php, transactions, yii2

I have two models, `Users` and `Students`. I want to insert data into these tables simultaneously. First, I save data into `Students` model and then into `Users` models.

Now, if data doesn't successfully get inserted into `Users` model there is already an entry into `Students` table. What I want is data entries into both model only if data can be successfully saved in both.

Now my **controller** code looks something like this:

```
    public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new Students();
            $userModel = new Users();    
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $userModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $userModel->save()) 
        {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'userModel' => $userModel,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

there is an error in users model and not return true when i call `$userModel->save()` . here, `$userModel->save()` return true and inserts data to the table.

Is there any other option to do this without any complication ?

Comment: You possibly have validation error with `Students` model. If you  want to save data by skipping validation then use `$model->save(false)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use transactions to ensure both models are saved correctly. Example:

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

try  {
    if ($model->save() && $userModel->save()) {
        $transaction->commit();
    } else {
        $transaction->rollBack();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 can already do that. Validate the input before save the data to the model:

```
if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() && $userModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post() ) {

   // Check validation
   if ($model->validate() && $userModel->validate()) {
       $model->save();
       $userModel->save();

   } else {
       // Throw error
   }
}
```

More info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

Comment: `$userModel->save()` can fail, and data consistency would be violated in this case. Better practice is to use tranactions

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what errors the Users model returns. Call getErrors() method in the else condition.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $userModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $userModel->save()) 
{
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
    var_dump($userModel->getErrors());
    ....
}
```

And you will see the errors that don't allow to save the Users model.