# How to save multiple models in one form in Yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I'm doing a form where I enter the data in two models in a single form. My question is how to record data entry in actionCreate () and call these models in a single form.
These are my inscritoController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Inscrito();
    $modelEmpresa = new Empresa();     
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelEmpresa->save() && $modelEmpresa->save()) 
        {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelEmpresa' => $modelEmpresa,
            ]);
        }
}
```

And Error:

PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Undefined variable: modelEmpresa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save multiple models at a time in Yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221212/save-multiple-models-at-a-time-in-yii2)

Comment: In your **create.php**  `return $this->render('_form', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelEmpresa' => $modelEmpresa,
            ]);`

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your controller

```
use app\models\Empresa;
```

Answer (score 0):

Load `Yii::$app->request->post()` to `$modelEmpresa` and confirm model call in your controller `use app\models\Empresa;`

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Inscrito();
        $modelEmpresa = new Empresa();     
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelEmpresa->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $modelEmpresa->save()) 
            {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelEmpresa' => $modelEmpresa,
                ]);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm call use app/models/empresa, inscritoController.pho. The code no works.

Comment: in your view  Empresa /create.php update  <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
          'modelEmpresa' => $modelEmpresa,
    ]) ?>